# Trying to not index catalog search result page

Tags: magento2, index

I'm trying to have the search result page not indexed.

/public/vendor/vaimo/theme-***/Magento_CatalogSearch/layout/catalogsearch_result_index.xml I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
    <meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW"/>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Move Items -->
    <move element="breadcrumbs" destination="main.content" before="-"/>
    <move element="ajax.message.placeholder" destination="main.content" before="-"/>
    <move element="messages" destination="main.content" before="-"/>
</body>
```

But it still gets indexed.

Comment: add also this catalogsearch_advanced_result.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U**nder your theme folder:**

- `Magento_CatalogSearch/layout/catalogsearch_advanced_result.xml`
- `Magento_CatalogSearch/layout/catalogsearch_result_index.xml`

And add the following content to those files (same content for both):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Comment: I don't have catalogsearch_advanced_result.xml.

Comment: copy that file and put in your theme

Comment: path :- vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/view/frontend/layout/catalogsearch_advanced_result.xml

Comment: Works now. Thank you!